# How to set focus on rendering redux form dynamically created in loops

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I am using Redux-form, I need to set focus on the text box when rendering on button click,  I have already using **autoFocus** but it will work on the second index of the loop

> also i have used document.getElementById('idname) as well

My code :

```
constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.inputFocus = this.utilizeFocus()
    }
const utilizeFocus = () => {
    const ref = React.createRef()
    const setFocus = () => {ref.current &&  ref.current.focus()}

    return {setFocus, ref} 
}
componentDidUpdate(){
        const set = this.inputFocus.ref.current;
        const sett = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(set);
        if(sett){
            sett.focus();
        }
    } 
<Field
   name={`${facility}.facilityRef`}
    component='input'
    type='text'
    ref={this.inputFocus}
    autoFocus
    aria-label="Facility Ref"
    />
```

> It works fine, I will get the focus on the particular field but it won't
>   go to next field, Means every rendering focus comes into the same
>   textbox. which life cycle I need to use for this.

I have integrated componentDidMount But it won't helpful

> I have also try refs functionality while searching from StackOverflow
>   but every where showing for button click But my question is for dynamically
>   created form then apply focus
>
> If you add autofocus, You won't need to write any above code, I am
>   using this code only for index 0 but on first rendering it is showing
>   perfect but we cannot go to the other text box

Comment: You mentioned that this is dynamically created, do you mean the button creates a new field? and that field is then focused?

Comment: Yes on click of button form created index by index, I have added autoFocus it works fine only on second index {index1} only , not on index 0 , Please help if you know

Comment: If you add autofocus, You won't need to write any above code, I am using this code only for index 0 but on first rendering it is showing perfect but we cannot go to the other text box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when rendering Focus on Input element with button click, For the first time we need to add timeout function for 2 milliseconds so that it can recognise the form

```
addForm(){
 setTimeout(() => {
        this.getFocus()
        }, 200);}


getFocus(){
        if(this.props.input.length === 1){
            document.getElementById("facilityRef0").focus();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This will help you auto-focus into the newly created field. Essentially, you want to create the refs dynamically so the inputs have a unique reference. Then in `componentDidUpdate()` simply target that ref and use `.focus()`.

Note that this is without Redux-Form, but you likely could create the same logic. :)

See codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-cookies-mz8gx

Working code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fields: []
    };
    this.nodes = new Map();
  }

  addField = () => {
    const { fields } = this.state;
    let newFieldObj = {
      id: fields.length,
      value: ""
    };

    this.setState({
      fields: [...fields, newFieldObj]
    });
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.fields.length !== this.state.fields.length) {
      const refs = Array.from(this.nodes.values());
      const newestRef = refs[refs.length - 1];
      newestRef.focus();
    }
  }

  handleOnChange = (e, inputId) => {
    const fieldsCopy = [...this.state.fields];

    const fieldToUpdate = fieldsCopy.find(field => field.id == inputId);

    fieldToUpdate.value = e.target.value;

    this.setState({
      fields: fieldsCopy
    });
  };

  renderFields = () => {
    const { fields } = this.state;
    return fields.map(field => {
      return (
        <div>
          <input
            key={field.id}
            ref={ref => this.nodes.set(field.id, ref)}
            value={field.value}
            onChange={e => this.handleOnChange(e, field.id)}
          />
        </div>
      );
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.renderFields()}</div>
        <button onClick={this.addField}>Add Field</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: it works but i cannot go forword to the next textbox, I mean when i click Keyboard Tab and start typing focus to come back on that text field again.

Comment: componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        const refs = Array.from(this.nodes.values());
          const newestRef = refs[refs.length - 1];
          const sett = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(newestRef);
          if(sett){
              sett.focus();
          }
        
      }

Comment: If you can add multiple text boxes created on single click at atime. this code won't work please help @chris

Comment: @Madhur right, this would only work if you are creating one field at a time. Which would make sense for a dynamic form. What is the importance of clicking the keyboard tab? The field already gets focused right after clicking Add Field.

Comment: clicking Tab or when you click with mouse on second text box and start typing , then foucs comes to the provious text box

Comment: Sorry, why would you want to go back to the previous textbox after typing in the 2nd? That seems like a more user experience. But this might also help you: https://codesandbox.io/s/auto-focus-into-next-input-yo4mg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198359/discussion-between-madhur-and-christopher-ngo).